# My website is entirely blank, tips to diagnose?

Tags: debugging, opencart

I have an ecommerce site built on OpenCart (1.5.0 i believe), which after inserting tracking code from Alexa.com and a block of code for redirecting to another site went entirely blank. Initially it worked, so I felt it was safe to save over my backups. But after refreshing the pages it was blank, and the 'view source' option in all my browsers (firefox, chrome, safari) revealed that there was no code reaching them. I then began to follow a series of debugging steps:

1. As my text editor was still open I undid all changes and reuploaded with no changes
2. I scanned the documents to be sure there were no issues in the text, with no discoveries
3. I ran it through W3C validation, with 2 warnings which are 1- no character encoding and 2- unable to determine parse mode.
4. contacted host for a server side restore though their earliest backup was a day after the problem began (it took 3 days of arguing to get them to initiate a restore)

In regards to these validation warnings, I am not sure what encoding should be used for OpenCart, ASCII or UTF-8 (which the validator resorted to) or what, in addition I am not sure if the template used with OpenCart would conflict with it if I were to declare encoding. In addition, I find it hard to believe that such a widely distributed product would have something this simple causing such a huge mistake because then all users would have this issue.

In regards to parse mode, the index page does declare parse mode (in the included header file).

In addition to all this, the validator is also claiming that it is not receiving code at all, which disables any chance of determining problems through that route.

The header and footer were both edited for these additions but are relatively long to include in this. The code used to edit were, for alexa `<!-- tracking code here -->` inserted into the head section of the header file, and the code for the footer was:

```
     <span style="display:inline-block;width:160px;height:30px;text-align:center;border:#000 1px dotted;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11px;background-color:#FFFFFF;"><strong style="display:block;padding:0px;margin:0px;">Reputation Management</strong><a href="http://www.submitexpress.com/" title="Submit Express - Search Engine Optimization Services" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11px;">Submit Express</a></span>
```

If anymore code is needed to help then please let me know, I am not looking for someone to fix my problem but to give me relevant tips to help figure it out myself or if they do provide a fix to educate me as how they managed it so I may be able to use the same debugging method. Thanks!

**EDIT:** The issue, as discovered thanks to Jay, is "PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  HTTP_HOST in ****/public_html/graphic-shack.com/index.php on line 40" and a google search has not revealed any effective results. This, to my untrained mind is jibberish, clarification would be greatly appreciated as line 40 is in fact a blank line, where as the text around it I can not post for some reason but will be viewable at http://graphic-shack.com/example.html

Comment: I did find suggestions to use isset() to solve similar errors, but I am by no means saavy in php, and wouldn't know where to begin nor what affects this could have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Cart uses UTF-8 throughout, so its definitely best to use that which your theme should set for the browser in the 
The first thing I would ask is have you got error reporting set up (NOT OPEN CARTS ONE) that logs php errors?
If not, then you need to do something like

```
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /path/to/custom/error.log
```

in your .htaccess file, so that you can log all your php errors to a file. this will need to be somewhere you can get the file, so change the path accordingly so you can view it.
Once you have that, you'll have a good base for working out the problem. I find it hard to believe that opencart has stopped because you added code. The most likely cause is a file missing, blanked or half written accidentally when saving or you've got some extra php code somewhere you shouldn't

== TEST.PHP CONTENT ==

```
<?php
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SERVER, true) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: great idea, I'll have to remember that though it sounds like something simple I should of already known. The error I am getting is  posted in the edit above, a google search of the error gave me all sorts of results, mostly for drupal, but when narrowed down to OpenCart I only came across 3 solutions none of which worked.

Comment: Oh, it is important to add that one of those results had the same exact effect as my site, but there was no solution given, it was a very short thread of about 3 posts.

Comment: Well the problem is that `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` isn't getting the value set bizzarely. You'll need to get in touch with your hosting company to find out why, but in the meantime, you can use

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'www.yoursite.com';` just above line 40 somewhere. That said, it shouldn't actually stop execution of the site

Comment: I tried your above temp-fix, and no joy. But I will run it past my host as well.

Comment: Did you change yoursite.com to your domain name?

Comment: yes of course. I did recently begin using a redirect (so anyone who uses http:// graphic-shack.com will be redirected to http://www . graphic-shack . com, perhaps this caused some conflict with opencart?

Comment: hehe just checking you would be amazed how many people just copy paste. To be honest, the redirect is unlikely to cause the issue. Best thing to do is contact your host as I've said, opencart is not going to be able to work without the $_SERVER variables set properly

Comment: The host said it is a code error, they think their servers are divine.

Comment: There's a simple test. Create a new file in the root of your site called test.php. In that file, put the code I've added to my answer above called test.php content

And go to yoursite.com/test.php, and see if there is a HTTP_HOST value in the output array

Comment: The results are too long to post here so to see what I got go to graphic-shack.com/test.php I don't know if any of this info is sensitive so if it is let me know after you view it and I'll delete it.

Comment: OK well you can see this line `[HTTP_HOST] => graphic-shack.com` Which is the line you need. Why it's not being set for opencart is a strange one

Comment: I hadn't made any changes to the site for weeks except what is mentioned above, its like it just got overwhelmed (which it was a slow week at best so I'd assume that isnt the case) or just broke... idk where to start, is there a way to reinstall without losing changes that you know of?

Comment: Not easily no if you've made changes to files. Do you have a redirect of any kind forcing the url? that could be an issue. Try removing the .htaccess file temporarily to see if that fixes it when you go to the site

Comment: My host says they fixed the problem after some encouragement :P basically they said by removing the catalog folder and replacing it with a unused one the problem is solved, now I am wondering how much  of an effect that has on my site structure and content, it is working but until I reupload the template (which they suggested may be the source of the issue so I am hesitant) I can't see all the effects.

Comment: By the point the error was generated, it hadn't even loaded anything to do with the catalog from what I can see. That sounds like a bullshit excuse from your hosting if you ask me...but at least you're getting somewhere with it :)

Comment: eh now I've got a huge problem, apparently if you delete the original catalog folder and replace it then you won't be able to upload templates, where if I replace it with the original it creates the error again. what a mess.

Comment: Do you freelance? I think I'd rather get this professionally done and save myself the headache at the end of the day, can you suggest a site for opencart freelance developers, etc?

Comment: Hi Nathan. Yes I do. email is jay [at] jaygilford [dot] com. I work with opencart all day every day :) Feel free to get in touch. Jay